# Ignore gets on second run in while loop, C

Tags: c

When i try to run this loop a second time It prints "enter a sentence" but jumps the `gets` part. And instaly asking for the answer to run the loop agian. I could use `scanf` if the problem wasent i will need white space.

Program will look like.

Enter a sentence: you

you

One more time? y/n:  y

Good choice!

Enter a sentence:

One more time? y/n:

```
int main(void){
  char user_input[20];
  int boolean = 0;
  char val[2];

  do{
      printf("Enter a sentence: ");
      gets(user_input);

      printf("%s\n", user_input);

      printf("One more time? y/n: ");
      scanf("%c", &val[0]);

      if(val[0] == 'y'){
        boolean = 1;
        printf("Good choice!\n");
      }else if(val[0] == 'n'){
        printf("You are really quiting?\n");
        boolean = 0;
      }

  }while(boolean);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: you probably still have a newline in the input steam after scanf()-ing out the `y/n` answer. since it's still there, when gets comes up, it'll just get a newline from the buffer and consider the input done.

Comment: Did´t work, Im priting out new line before "enter sentence"

Comment: that's irrelevant. that's stdout. there'll still be a newline in stdin from the user hitting `Y<enter>`

Comment: FYI: **`gets`** is so bad, it was even thrown out of the C99 standard (even though they are all sticklers for backward-compatibility there, as is proper). The only thing you need to know about it is "**Don't use it. Ever!**"

Comment: I just picked up C i only know about scanf and gets yet, Is their a better function to input strings with white space than get?

Comment: In c gets() is the best function to input strings with white space, but you need to be a bit careful to use that...  - @Nicco

Comment: @KhairulBasar : If you read the man pages, it clearly says, "Never use gets.", under the BUGS label. gets is not the best way. You can rather use "fgets" to read a string.

Comment: Use `fgets()` rather than `gets()`. Note that `fgets()` also returns a buffer with the typical trailing `'\n'`, unlike the former valid function `gets()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you input ans of y/n scanf() takes the character and the newline is taken by gets()..
your code need a little modification like this...

```
int main(void)
{
     char user_input[20];
     int boolean = 0;
     char val[2];

  do{
     printf("Enter a sentence: ");
     gets(user_input);

     printf("%s\n", user_input);

     printf("One more time? y/n: ");
     scanf("%c", &val[0]);
     getchar();

     if(val[0] == 'y')
     {
         boolean = 1;
         printf("Good choice!\n");
     }
     else if(val[0] == 'n')
     {
         printf("You are really quiting?\n");
         boolean = 0;
     }

  }while(boolean);

 return 0;
}
```

getchar() function takes the newline character...so, gets() doesn't take newline and no error occurs...

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you still have new line character inside your stdin buffer, thus "gets" takes
that newline character as its input and you don't get a chance to enter yours.
use **getchar()** after scanf to read the newline character like :

```
scanf("%c", &val[0]);
getchar();
```

or you can make some adjustment inside your scanf function :

```
scanf("\n%c", &val[0]); // insert a newline character in the beginning.
```

Comment: Note: `scanf(" %c", &val[0]);` has the same effect as `scanf("\n%c", &val[0]);`: consume optional leading white-space before scanning a `char` into `val[0]`,